Restricting a homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p^\times$
Let $\operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{Gp}}\left(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p^\times\right)$ be the set of all group homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ to all roots of unity in $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$. Let $\mathcal{F}\colon \operatorname{Gp}\rightarrow \operatorname{Set}$ be the forgetful functor.
Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, denote by $\overline{A}$ the quotient set of $A$ by the relation $\sim$ that $a\sim b\Leftrightarrow a-b\in\mathbb{Z}$.
If $$\left\{\mathcal{F}(f)\vert_{\overline{A}}\in\operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{Set}}\left(\overline{A},\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p^\times\right)\colon f\in \operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{Gp}}\left(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p^\times\right)\right\}$$
is a finite set, then how can we prove that $A\subseteq \frac{1}{N}\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ for some positive positive integer $N$?

Yes…(…………………….)

We only need to consider homomorphisms in the category $Ab$ of abelian groups, so moving over there.
A useful fact is that the multiplicative group $k^*$ of the algebraic closure $k:=\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$ is
divisible, and hence an injective object of $Ab$. In other words, if
$K_1\le K_2$ are abelian groups, every homomorphism $K_1\to k^*$ is gotten by restricting some homomorphism $K_2\to k^*$.
Let $M$ be the subgroup of $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ generated by $\overline{A}$. Any homomorphism $f:M\to k^*$ is fully determined by its restriction to $\overline{A}$,
so we are given that the abelian group $H:=Hom(M,k^*)$ is finite. I want to prove that the choice $N=|H|$ works.
Assume that there exists an element
$$\frac mn+\Bbb{Z}\in M\setminus\overline{\frac1N\Bbb{Z}[1/p]},\quad \gcd(m,n)=1.$$
Write $n=p^\ell n'$ with $p\nmid n'$. It follows that $n'\nmid N$ and that the element $z=(m/n')+\Bbb{Z}\in M$ has order $n'$. Let $C=\langle z\rangle$ be the
cyclic group of order $n'$. As $p\nmid n'$ the group $k^*$ has a root of unity $\zeta$ of
order $n'$. Consider the homomorphism $f:C\to k^*$ defined by $f(j z)=\zeta^j$ for all $j$. It has order $n'$ in the group $Hom(C,k^*)$. Let $\tilde{f}\in Hom(M,k^*)$ be any homomorphism extending $f$ (injectivity of $k^*$ comes to the fore again). Its order in $H$ must be a multiple of $n'$. Consequently $n'\mid N$,
which is a contradiction.
